# Calculate force to move by given distance chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, spritebuilder

How to apply a impulse that make ball fly given distance in Cocos2d?

Comment: depends on the mass of the ball, if you want to ignore mass set velocity directly instead of applyImpulse

Comment: _physicsNode.space.gravity is ccp(0,-100);
_ball.physicsBody.mass = 1.0f;
I want to shoot my ball 800 pixels up. What power i should use.

Comment: impulse is multiplied by inverse of mass (1.0/mass), ie assuming velocity is 0 then: velocity = impulse * (1.0 / 1.0) or in other words: velocity = impulse in this case ... but then integrating gravity over time in this equation is beyond me. If you used impulse of y=900 the ball would be 800 pixels up in the next frame. Impulse 500: 400 + 300 = 700 in two frames but too far in the third frame.

Comment: How fast do you want to get it there?  There's more to the physics of it than just force.

Comment: I want time to by const no matter to distance.

Comment: Then you want to make a velocity variable that is inversely proportional to the distance traveled.

Comment: Can you guys please check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898824/how-velocity-impacts-on-ccsprite-in-cocos2d-chipmunk and suggest me how distance, time, height, angle, etc. are being calculated by setting velocity only..? in Chipmunk? Because as seen in console in question I use same velocity but distances travelled are different. I want distance travelled same, so, need to apply precise velocity factor.